Subtract constant 1 from pivot table in excel
I have a pivot table with a numerical column. I want to subtract number '1' from 'count of serial number' column. I tried to use Fields, Items, sets and entered formula as = ='Number' - 1. But this gives -1 through out. Not getting what is the mistake.
What I have:Pivot table with Serial number column



Number
calc col




4
-1


24
-1



What I want is below:



Number
calc col




4
3


24
23




Hi, check this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q04hrbqoG0g

Hi Thanks for sharing. I tried the same with subtracting 'Serial No' - 1. But it only gives me -1 as result. :( Not getting why it is printing -1 and not subtracting .

Also there is no tutorials or video on google where we can subtract a constant from pivot column. There are videos on subtracting or adding column with another column. In my case it is  - 1.

here is a small working example.




Hi, Thanks for the reply. Initially I tried this but this only gives me -1 as answer for all rows. But if I subtract 2 pivot rows then it works fine. but not with a pivot column and a constant.
